# Use HTTP API with AWS Amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-amplify

I have the "new" HTTP API with a DynamoDB and lambda, I want to provide support for my app to the macOS computers. Is it possible to use the HTTP API Gateway with Amplify? I only see an option for GraphQL and REST

Thaks